# Combining multiple forms/controllers on a single page

Tags: phalcon

I've asked this question in phalcon forums as well but haven't received a response yet.

I'm trying to learn phalcon by examining the examples. Currently I'm studying Vokura example.

What I want to do is, instead of going to Login and Signup pages seperately, I'd like to have them on one page, say index..

I've looked at Partial templates and tried to use:

```
//views>index.volt
<div>{{ partial("session/login") }}</div>
<div>{{ partial("session/signup") }}</div>
```

I also included:

```
//controllers>IndexController.php
use Vokuro\Forms\LoginForm;
use Vokuro\Forms\SignUpForm;
```

However, that threw an error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: form
```

My question is, what do I need to do to include both login and signup forms on the index page without making changes to LoginForm.php, SignupForm.php, SessionController.php so I can also use links to go to the individual login and signup pages.

Hope I'm making any sense, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Vokuros' partials of [login](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/views/session/login.volt) and [signup](https://github.com/phalcon/vokuro/blob/master/app/views/session/signup.volt) forms it's getting a little bit tricky.

Both of them require a `$form` variable devined in view, both of them uses different objects under that variable. In case you don't want to edit those partial here's a two-step guide.

## 1 Instaniate your forms

During index controller you are declaring your usages. But forms have to be instatiated. Below is example you may want to adjust for your case:

```
use Vokuro\Forms\LoginForm;
use Vokuro\Forms\SignUpForm;

class DefaultController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller {

    function indexAction() {
        // declaration for further manipulations
        $scriptLoginForm = new LoginForm();
        $scriptSignUpForm = new SignUpForm();

        // manipulations space
        // ....

        // defining for view. Notice, that I presented here
        // that variables in View will have different names.
        $this->view->setVar('loginForm', $scriptLoginForm);
        $this->view->setVar('signUpForm', $scriptSignInForm);

        // default for using one form in view would be:
        // $this->view->setVar('form', $formInstance);
    }
}
```

## 2 Define `$form` durng view.

Than you may want to manipulate a bit in your view,to set up proper form instance at proper moment.

```
{% set form = loginForm %}
<div>{{ partial("session/login") }}</div>

{% set form = signUpForm %}
<div>{{ partial("session/signup") }}</div>
```

or according to [manual](http://docs.phalconphp.com/pl/latest/reference/volt.html#view-integration):

```
<div>{{ partial("session/login", ['form': loginForm]) }}</div>
<div>{{ partial("session/signup", ['form': signUpForm]) }}</div>
```

not tested example, but should work more or less this way.

**note that this is exclusive example for Vokuro**. When developing your own parts, you probably will differ varables names based on partials, eg. in `partial/login` using `$formLogin` etc.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. It's been a long time since this question and i moved away from phalcon due to lack of support, i'm fairly new to whole mvc scene and not an expert on php so i decided it was a mistake starting off with a framework that is not widely in use. I appreciate your answer. If i'm not wrong, i had done something similar to your answer but it complain about csrf being already defined etc.. I might set it up again just to see if this is working. Thank you again

Comment: So you may have done it right. CSRF is all different story, but having that error suggests previous steps working ok ;)